# Ubuntu camera not capturing full width

Tags: webcam, camera

Some camera apps like Webcamoid don't take the full width that the camera can see. How do I make the camera capture the maximum width and height? I'm using Ubuntu 22.10.

Taken by Webcamoid:

[image: picture from Webcamoid 9.0.0]

Taken by Windows camera:

[image: picture from Windows camera]

Comment: Can you change the resolution in Webcamoid settings?

Comment: @Archisman I searched for an option to change resolution but didn't find one.

Comment: Can you try the application cheese? `sudo apt install cheese` I know that it certainly has an option to change resolution. High resolution images seem to have a much wider angle.

Comment: @Archisman It does, but a lot of features and effects that are in Webcamoid are missing. Another thing is, videos seem to have lower quality and less fps in cheese.

Comment: @EzzeldienRashad It's something to do with the driver itself and what OS the laptop is designed for. You respin any webcam software and mess around with the software code and see if you can make it better.